# Losing $_POST data after moving to HTTPS

Tags: php, https, redirect

Since setting up a redirect in .htaccess I have achieved my goal of forcing WWW. and removing all .php extensions. However I don't think the use of https is working as my $_post is now null on submitting my form. Please help.

**UPDATE** -- HTTPS I think is ok. I remove the last two rows of my .htaccess code dealing with removing of php extensions and my form works again. So the questions is now, how do I remove the php extensions on the website without losing my $_POST data. -- **UPDATE**

I've tried switching between %{SERVER_PORT} 80 and %{HTTPS} !on in my .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC]
#Tried using... Rewritecond  %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
# This hides the php extensions
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

Here is my form mark up:

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="productRequest" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo "..".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?item=".$item."&amp;design=".$design."&amp;option=".$option."&amp;add=Y"; ?>" method="POST">
```

Note I have tried https://www.example.co.uk.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] too

When the form calls itself I have:

```
$item = $_GET['item'];
$design = $_GET['design'];
$option = $_GET['option'];
$add = $_GET['add'];

if(!isset($item))
    {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit;
    }
else if($add=='Y')
    {
    print_r($_POST);
    exit;
    }
```

I just get: Array ()

Comment: Do you actually __call__ your php script using https? If not, the Cross-Origin-Policy might be in your way.

Comment: Can you post your full form html?

Comment: Here is the form button, the type is changed to 'submit' if everything is entered and this is working as I can see in the web inspector that it's changing and the page is called as I see the results of the print_r($_post) <div id='formButton2'><input id='addItem' class='button' type='button' onclick='javascript:warning()' alt='Add to Basket'  value='Add to basket'/></div>

Comment: Use a `<form>` `action` URL that does not need to be redirected! If you want to remove .php etc from the URL, write an `action` URL that does not contain .php to begin with. No redirect, no problem.

Comment: I'm using a <form> action which has .php but the last two lines of the site wide redirect in the .htaccess file is causing issues.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, that’s the issue. Use an `action` which doesn’t need to be redirected because it’s already the URL you desire.

Comment: Yes the problem now is how do I visibly remove the php extensions throughout the site in such a way that the for action https://www.example.com/pagewithform.php isn't touched.

Comment: `action="/pagewithform"`. Boom, done.

Comment: Apologies deceze I stupidly assumed that the action would need the .php extension in order for it to no the page. Hence all working now!

Answer (score 1):

POST data is not resend after redirect.
This is a wanted feature to enable a redirect after computing the post data (e.g. after file upload to show stats).

Solution: Change `<form>` to https.

Comment: as stated, I've changed the form action to:  https: //www.example.co.uk.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']